# Compare Text Files. Record Line #s that Match

Tags: powershell, compare, line-numbers

I have two text files.

```
$File1 = "C:\Content1.txt"
$File2 = "C:\Content2.txt"
```

I'd like to compare these to see if they have the same number of lines and then I'd like to record the line number of each line that matches. I realize that sounds ridiculous but this is what I've been asked to do at my work.

I can compare them a lot of ways. I decided to do the following:

```
$File1Lines = Get-Content $File1 | Measure-Object -Line
$File2Lines = Get-Content $File2 | Measure-Object -Line
```

I'd like to test it with an if statement so that if they don't match, then I can start an earlier process over again.

```
if ($file1lines.lines -eq $file2lines.lines) 
{ Get the Line #s that match and proceed to the next step} 
else {Start Over}
```

I'm unsure how to record the line #s that match. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "record the line #s that match"?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart The files will be the same length so from there I'd like to save in another document or rather variable, the line number these matches occur on. Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: Have you considered `Compare-Object`? It doesn't provide line numbers, but it may be what you are looking for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really pretty simple since `Get-Content` reads the file in as an array of strings, and you can index that array simply enough.

```
Do{
    <stuff to generate files>
}While(($File1 = GC $PathToFile1).Count -ne ($File2 = GC $PathToFile2).count)

$MatchingLineNumbers = 0..($File1.count -1) | Where{$File1[$_] -eq $File2[$_]}
```

Since arrays in PowerShell use a 0 based index we want to start at 0 and go for however many lines the files have. Since `.count` starts at 1 not 0 we need to subtract 1 from the total count. So if your file has 27 lines `$File1.count` will equal 27. The index for those lines ranges from 0 (first line) to 26 (last line). The code `($File1.count - 1)` would effectively come out to 26, so `0..26` starts at 0, and counts to 26.

Then each number goes to a `Where` statement that checks that specific line in each file to see if they are equal. If they are then it passes the number along, and that gets collected in `$MatchingLineNumbers`. If the lines don't match the number isn't passed along.

Comment: Cool array piping, love it :)

Comment: Rad! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get an intersection first, then find the index.

#### file1.txt

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line11
Line21
Line31
Line12
Line22
Line32
```

#### file2.txt

```
Line1
Line11
Line21
Line31
Line12
Line222
Line323
Line214
Line315
Line12
Line22
Line32
```

**test.ps1**

```
$file1 = Get-Content file1.txt
$file2 = Get-Content file2.txt
$matchingLines = $file1 | ? { $file2 -contains $_ }

$file1Lines = $matchingLines | % { Write-Host "$([array]::IndexOf($file1, $_))"  }
$file2Lines = $matchingLines | % { Write-Host "$([array]::IndexOf($file2, $_))"  }
```

**Output**

$file1Lines

```
    0
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
```

$file2Lines

```
    0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    10
    11
```

Comment: That doesn't really check if lines match, it just checks to see if any given line in `$file1` exists as a line in `$file2`, regardless of index, and then looks those lines up. I mean, this is excellent, but at this point I think you're better off making objects for each match to show the line text, and then its location in each file if you're going this far.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician You and I are basically doing the same thing, just in different ways. You are searching by incrementing numbers (index), I was searching with the content itself. It does check if the lines match, that's what `$matchingLines = $file1 | ? { $file2 -contains $_ }` is doing. `$matchingLines` is also an array, which gets piped to printing the line numbers in both files.

Comment: No, mine compares line by line, yours *should* check if a line exists, and then give the index of it in each file. Also, yours doesn't appear to work, because line 2 (index location 1) in File1 is 'Line2' which does not appear at all in File2, yet it appears in your $file1Lines and $file2Lines.

Comment: Also, I don't understand "your doesn't appear to work". Did you run it?

Comment: It really isn't about my code being better, to be honest your answer is great, it gives a more in depth comparison than mine does, I just don't think it's what the OP was looking for. Not bad, or wrong, just not as applicable. I did not run it, but I did explain why I said that. I looked at your sample files, and output, and the input does not justify the output.